# Jquery add property to appended div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a slideshow plugin that lets me set the div in which I want image captions to appear. I'm creating the caption div dynamically in js using `append()` but the caption doesn't appear because I assume the div has to be in HTML prior to loading the js script.

Append function in js

```
.append('<span class="image-wrapper current"><a class="advance-link"><div id="caption"></div></a></span>')
```

I want to display captions in the div named caption.

When initializing the plugin I have the following options.

```
var gallery = $('#thumbs').galleriffic({
                    delay:                     2200,
                    numThumbs:                 20,
                    captionContainerSel:       '#caption'
etc...
```

How can I make the caption appear in the `#caption` div that I appended?

Comment: Why are you appending it? Why don't you add it with the rest of the HTML?

Comment: It's part of a larger function that generates more data in the append. I didn't add all that for simplicity.

Comment: does the append happen before the `galleriffic` implementation?

Comment: Can we see this up somewhere? Lots of possible places this could be going wrong. For example, do your thumbnail container elements have  child elements with the 'caption' class?

Comment: @Jed, the js is http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/js/jquery.galleriffic.js I'm just adding the `#caption` div in the `var newSlide` in the append function, then initializing the script with the custom options.

Comment: Is there actually a caption to display in the thumb(s) container? This is from the gallerific documentation: "It is important to specify the 'thumb' class for the link that should serve as the thumbnail and the 'caption' class for the element that should serve as the caption. When an image is selected for display in the slideshow, any elements with the 'caption' class will be rendered within the specified caption container element above."

Comment: Yes the captions appears when I add it to a div that was in HTML before the js. It just doesn't work with appended divs.

Comment: Are you appending multiples of this div? If so, you shouldn't have multiple elements with the same div id. Sorry if these are silly suggestions. Just hard to know exactly how it's set up without seeing it in action. Is there no place to see your site more in action? A jsFiddle at least?

Comment: Thanks, I'll set up a better example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be wrong, but i would think the jQuery plugin is looking for an actual jQuery object. So rather than,

```
var gallery = $('#thumbs').galleriffic({
                delay:                     2200,
                numThumbs:                 20,
                captionContainerSel:       '#caption'
```

you have

```
var gallery = $('#thumbs').galleriffic({
                delay:                     2200,
                numThumbs:                 20,
                captionContainerSel:       $('#caption')
```

Give that a try and let us know.